# How can I push the first element of array, reverse the array, & push reversed array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, reverse

So I am trying to learn PHP but I am having trouble finding the appropriate functions.

I am currently trying to reverse an array given:
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

My goal is to push an element, reverse the array, and push another element, until it reaches the length of array.
so first iteration: aedcb
   2nd iteration: aebcd
   3rd iteration: aebdc
Can anyone recommend php functions I can look up and read through to achieve this?
This is my current code, and I know there's a way to just create a function, loop through the array, filter & push, but I am having trouble getting the proper php functions, and creating a reverse function

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
// aedcb
// aebcd
// aebdc

$reversedArray = [];

array_push($reversedArray, $array[0]);

$rev = array_reverse($array);

array_push($reversedArray, $rev[0]);

 $rev2 = array_reverse($rev);

 array_push($reversedArray, $rev2[1]);

 $rev3 = array_reverse($rev2);
 array_push($reversedArray, $rev3[1]);

 $rev4 = array_reverse($rev3);

array_push($reversedArray, $rev4[2]);

?>
```

Which prints out my end goal. But this will definitely not work if given an array, or object containing more items than my current array.

Comment: Should the result after the first iteration be `aebdc` or `aedcb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't have to reverse the array at all. Just remove items one by one alternating between the beginning and the end.

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

$result = [];
$takeFromBeginning = true;
while(count($array))
{
    if($takeFromBeginning) {
        $result[] = array_shift($array);
    } else {
        $result[] = array_pop($array);
    }

    $takeFromBeginning = !$takeFromBeginning;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result for `$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];` should be `aebdc` you could use a loop with the [modulo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%` operator and index either from the left or the right side into the `$array`.

For example:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

function customReverse($array) {
    $reversedArray = [];
    $count = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $reversedArray[] = $i % 2 === 0 ? $array[$i / 2] : $array[$count - ($i / 2)];
    }
    return $reversedArray;
}

print_r(customReverse($array));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => e
    [2] => b
    [3] => d
    [4] => c
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/LjRJD)